# Call a fragment from Navigation drawer ClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer in my MainActivity and I've set up the ClickListener:

```
mMenuList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

In the Main onCreate method, I start the fragment with a default view:

```
MyMapFragmentActivity fragMap = new MyMapFragmentActivity();
FragmentManager fragMgr = getFragmentManager();
fragMgr.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragMap).commit();
```

That is fine, but when I click an item in the nav drawer, I need to be able to open the fragment again, but with some different options.

The question is, the ClickListener is its own class:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

            default:
                break;
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mMenuList);
    }
}
```

How do I get access to the MyMapFragmentActivity object within this DrawerItemClickListener class so that I can call it with different params ?  Or is that not the way it should be done ?

Comment: Nav drawer is hosted by MainActivity right? You can handle listitem click in that activity try to Google it.

Comment: Look at the official document here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks. If you have problems, please come back here ;)

Comment: well obviously I have looked at that document and searched around, if you look at my specific question, it is not covered in that guide, that is why i am here

Comment: in the Google doc it creates the new fragment inside the clickListener - what I need to do is pass the fragment INTO the clickListener, because I already have it open